# Heroku: SSL is not enabled

Tags: ssl, heroku

So my Rails (3.2.1) app was working fine on Heroku.  Then I set `config.force_ssl = true` in my production config file, upon opening the file, I now got the "SSL is not enabled" error.  I thought Heroku allows you to piggyback their SSL certs, but it is not working for me.

What I've tried:

- using `heroku addons:add piggyback_ssl` (fails, as the add-on is now standard..)
- validating my account (shouldn't be necessary, but I tried it anyway)
- changing my `config.force_ssl = false`, but my app still tries to use SSL...

Answer (score 2):

I may a bit late, but the reason that your browser still redirects you to https even if you have that option turned off in Rails has to do with the "Strict-Transport-Security" header (HSTS).

Comment: This would certainly explain [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10444780/372643) too.

Comment: page no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the **Piggyback SSL** addon as follows:

```
heroku addons:add ssl:piggyback
```

Once that's installed and your app has been restarted, it should be accessible at both of the following addresses:

- `http://your-app.heroku.com`
- `https://your-app.heroku.com`

Comment: yeah, that's the first thing I tried.  It gives a message that ssl piggyback now comes standard, and that I don't need to use that command anymore... and then continues to give me the error....  Also, I went back and set force_ssl to false, and the app still tries to load https, and gives me the error.  I can't access the app at http, it just keeps re directing to https...

Comment: You said you tried to install **piggyback_ssl**, so I was confused. I'm not sure then. Does SSL work locally?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have caught Heroku in the middle of a rollout. As of a few weeks ago, Piggyback SSL is now enabled for all users/apps by default. If you're still seeing the "SSL is not enabled" error, you should contact Support.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog/10