# rails 4 - adding force ssl - why it does not switch back to http after https request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, https

I am testing force_ssl in my Rails 4 app , so I added in the todos_controller:

```
 class Users::TodosController < ApplicationController
 ....
 force_ssl :only => [:test_ssl]  unless Rails.env.development?
```

I added into config/application.rb

```
 config.force_ssl = false
```

I modified vhost , restarted apache ...
when the user request   ...todos/test_ssl, the https request is performed, ok

however , once being on this pas , the user go back to the home page, the request is still performed with https , it doesn't swithc back to http...

should I insert force_ssl = false in the other controllers  ? I thought the config parameter would be avaolable for all other controllers ...  am I wrong ? or should I use the gem rack-ssl-enforcer ?

Comment: ugh i wished someone answered you lol

Comment: Because HSTS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629397/how-to-disable-http-strict-transport-security