# How do I force SSL and also have a www domain URL redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, heroku, https, hsts

I have a domain running on example.com and `https://example.com` on Heroku. I have a URL redirect on my name server from www to `https://example.com`. I have `config.force_ssl = true` set in `config/environment/production.rb`. The domain URL redirect works only on http, not https. It works in Chrome the first time I type www.example.com. However it fails the 2nd time I use www.example.com. It gives a 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' with a 307 Internal Redirect.

```
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Location: https://www.example.com/
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS
```

This is despite the domain service always giving `Location: https://example.com` via `curl`. Where is Chrome getting `https://www*` from? I saw https://superuser.com/a/881431/130929 about deleting the HSTS entries from Chrome at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`. If I do that for both example.com and www.example.com, then it works only the first time for www.example.com again. example.com and `https://example.com` always works. What's worse is that in Firefox, after loading the page, simply using example.com fails because Firefox automatically adds a `https://www`. How can I use HTTPS on the root domain and redirect www to the root domain? I don't care about handling `https://www.example.com` as no one would type that. They would only mistakenly type www.example.com.

Comment: Do you have SSL cert?

Comment: Yes, see the part where I say `I have a domain running on ... https://example.com`. It is in the first sentence. Also see the part where I say `https://example.com always works` near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629397/ddg#10632901

I saw in `curl -i https://example.com` that it was returning

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
```

The max age is 6 months. `includeSubDomains` probably means to include `www`. So I added

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :disable_hsts_subdomains

  def disable_hsts_subdomains
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'max-age=15552000;'
  end
```

Which just removed `includeSubDomains` so it wouldn't try to redirect `www` without reaching out to the host first (DNS server), which would send the redirect to the proper root domain.

Comment: It still doesn't work in Firefox 60.0.2. I have filed a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1468353. Firefox will _still_ add `https://` to a domain `www.example.com` even though it no longer has `includeSubdomains` and even though I removed the domain from `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` (Firefox's version of `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`).